# C++ Van loading program

Tags: c++

I am stuck.

I have been given this problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljMTJ.png

The code I've written so far is this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

char cIn;
char full;

int capacity = 750;
int numVans = 1;

float heaviestVan = 0;
float payload = 0;
float parcelWeight;

bool emptyBelt = false;

int main()
{
    bool end = false;
        while(!end)
        {
            start:
            cout << string(25, '\n');
            cout << endl << "Pauls Premier Parcels (PPP)" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Van being loaded is number: " << numVans << endl << endl;
            cout << "The payload of van " << numVans << " is currently " << payload << " / 750kg" << endl << endl;
            cout << "Is the belt full? ('Y' or 'N'): ";
            cin >> full;


        if (full == 'Y' || 'y')
        {
            while (!emptyBelt)
            {
                cout << endl << endl << "Please enter the weight of the next parcel: ";
                cin >> parcelWeight;

                if (parcelWeight > 120)
                {
                    cout << "The maximum parcel weight is 120kg, please weigh a different parcel: ";
                    cin >> parcelWeight;
                }

                if (payload + parcelWeight <= capacity)
                {
                    payload = payload + parcelWeight;
                    cout << endl << "The parcel has been loaded onto the van" << endl << endl;
                    goto start;
                }

                else
                {
                    cout << endl << "The current van has reached capacity and is being dispatched" << endl;
                    //numVans = numVans + 1;

                    if(payload > heaviestVan)
                    {
                        heaviestVan = payload;
                    }
                    payload = 0;

                    cout << endl << endl << endl << "Vans dispatched: " << numVans;
                    cout << endl << endl << "Weight of heaviest van: " << heaviestVan;

                } 
            }   
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I need to implement a statement asking the user to place parcels on the belt if the belt is empty, right now It just continues running the program.

Also the user could enter anything besides `Y` or `y` and the program would still run.

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: Please state the problem with the current code. I.e. what you are expecting and what it is doing

Comment: don't try to write the whole program at once. Try to write a loop that just asks about being full, and continues or stops. When that's good, fill in the body of the loop with all the other variables. Both `while (!end)` and `goto` are strange choices for your flow of control.

Comment: @Jérôme Leducq my apologies, my question is how to write the code that asks the user to place parcels on the belt if it is empty.

Comment: @KateGregory Okay, thanks for the tip :)

Comment: @EdHeal I'd like to implement a statement to ask the user to add parcels to the belt if they state the belt is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try rewriting

```
if (full == 'Y' || 'y')
```

to

```
if ((full == 'Y') || (full == 'y'))
```

Some explanation:

```
if (full == 'Y' || 'y')
```

is the same as

```
if ((full == 'Y') || ('y'))
```

which is the same as

```
if ((full == 'Y') || true)
```

which is the same as

```
if (true)
```

regardsless of the value of the variable full.

Comment: Please change the second snippet to `if (full == 'Y' || full == 'y')`. See C++ operator precedence.

Comment: @АндрейБеньковский - And what do you expect to gain by doing that? The answer is.... nothing.

Comment: @StillLearning Less code is usually better (clearer). In this particular case redundant braces don't make the code much worse, but in a more complex expression it would make a difference. I'll suggest an edit to your answer.